# riak-erlang-client fails to ping riak node

Tags: erlang, riak

My riak node is not responding to ping yet everything seems ok

```
(myclient@127.0.0.1)2> {ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("127.0.0.1", 10018).  
{ok,<0.217.0>}
(myclient@127.0.0.1)3> riakc_pb_socket:ping(Pid).
** exception exit: disconnected
(myclient@127.0.0.1)4> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Dec-2014::04:41:22 ===
** Generic server <0.217.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {req_timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.306>}
** When Server state == {state,"127.0.0.1",10018,false,false,undefined,
                           undefined,
                           {[],[]},
                           1,[],infinity,100}
** Reason for termination == 
** disconnected
```

What is that i am not doing right??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Port 10018 is the HTTP listening port for a Riak cluster set up in development mode, but you're using the protocol buffers client. Try port 10017 instead.

Comment: I have flowed the **FIVE MINUTES INSTALL** and that is where the ports on which these five nodes are listening are listed at [Basho website](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/). Now how can i know the port on which each node is listening?

Comment: You can check the `riak.conf` file for each node in your dev cluster, it specifies the various listening ports.